# Install application on all user profiles created in android tablet OS 4.2 or greater

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, user-profile

I have an issue where when I create and install one application using a selected profile, it is available to that profile only. I need the application to be installed for all user profiles. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user with the primary profile (e.g., the tablet owner) can set that up. You, a developer, cannot force your app into other profiles. If there's some hack that supports this, it's a security flaw.

Comment: so is it possible that we can install the application in primary profile even though selected profile is different? and using that primary profile, we can grant access to this application to all profiles through any menifest settings?